# Storing emberjs hasMany model on server?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

So here is the model structure that i currently have in place

```
// match.js
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('string'),
    match: DS.attr('number'),
    players: DS.hasMany('player')
});
//player.js
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
    pid: DS.attr('number'),
    match: DS.attr('number'),
    name: DS.attr('string'),
    point: DS.attr('number'),
    home: DS.attr('boolean'),
    squard: DS.belongsTo('squard'),
    selected: DS.attr('boolean', {default: false})
});
```

I create a new squad on client side and use push `players`s using the following code

```
let player - this.store.peekRecord('player', id);
let squard = this.store.peekRecord('squard', 1);
squard.get('players').pushObject(player);
```

I tried using `squard.save()` but that doesn't send the array of players with it. How can i push those changes to server ?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to push the full list of players to the server when you save a squad, you will want to use the ember [embedded-records mixin](https://www.emberjs.com/api/ember-data/3.1/classes/DS.EmbeddedRecordsMixin).

Create a squad adapter and add the following to it.

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.RESTSerializer.extend(DS.EmbeddedRecordsMixin, {
  attrs: {
    players: { embedded: 'always' }
  }
});
```

This will cause the players array to be serialized and included in the squad payload.

Answer (score 1):

Using [DS.EmbeddedRecordsMixin](https://www.emberjs.com/api/ember-data/3.1/classes/DS.EmbeddedRecordsMixin) as suggested by Trenton Trama's answer should only be used together with [DS.RESTSerializer](https://www.emberjs.com/api/ember-data/3.1/classes/DS.RESTSerializer), which is not the default one.

If using [DS.JSONAPISerializer](https://www.emberjs.com/api/ember-data/3.1/classes/DS.JSONAPISerializer), which implements [JSON API specification](http://jsonapi.org/) and used as default, customizing [`shouldSerializeHasMany()`](https://www.emberjs.com/api/ember-data/3.1/classes/DS.JSONAPISerializer/methods/serializeHasMany?anchor=shouldSerializeHasMany) is a way better approach.

Have in mind that there are good reasons not to do a full replacement of has-many relationships. A JSON API compliant server might not support it at all:

> Note: Since full replacement may be a very dangerous operation, a server may choose to disallow it. For example, a server may reject full replacement if it has not provided the client with the full list of associated objects, and does not want to allow deletion of records the client has not seen. ([Source](http://jsonapi.org/format/#crud-updating-resource-relationships))